# Is there any way to run background process by loading .a in background

Tags: c++, ios

We are facing “Invalid address” crashes while our app is in background.

We are using CURL to make API calls via CPP library. We add API calls to the queue and CURL makes the calls to server asynchronously  but when app is in background the CPP library is unloaded by iOS , so when CURL try to access the CPP Library we are facing “Invalid address” crash.

Is there any way to run API calls via CPP library in background ?

Comment: Can you provide more information about how you are using cURL in iOS (which is quite unusual). Have you built libcurl and linked it to your app? Why do you think "the library is unloaded"? This is impossible for .a libraries. Please provide the full crash dump. iOS apps in the background are stopped except for very specific use cases, e.g. file downloads initiated by `URLSessionConfiguration.background`. Are you familiar with these restrictions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.